# Oracle unique constraint error message

Tags: oracle, constraints

I am maintaining a legacy application and I recently got contacted that people are getting an error message when they try to fill one of our oracle tables. Now, those oracle tables are not in our care, but I still want to try out something to help find the problem.

Anyway, the error message is the following:

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (REO0.**PK_TableName**) violated :

I know I can find a lot of information online through google and here about this error message. That is not what my question is about.

> *The question is*: the tablename shown here (which I put in bold), is that
>   the name of the table, or is the
>   **PK_** part added to represent 'primary key' ?

Reason why I ask is: I can't directly get to this database, but somehow I can see all tables in REO0 and I can find one with *TableName* but not one with *PK_TableName* as the name for a table. So if this PK_ would refer to something like 'primary key' (which the constraint of is violated) then it would make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PK_tablename` is the name of the constraint, and as *Alex Poole* states in a good comment, it has been specified in the DDL (`CREATE TABLE ... (columns, CONSTRAINT PK_tablename PRIMARY KEY(columns...) )`, or `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT PK_tablename PRIMARY KEY(columns...)` or `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_tablename ON ... (columns)` for example). When no name has been given, Oracle generates a name which begins with `SYS`.

Note that usually `PK_x` suggests a primary key for table x, but your constraint might also be a foreign key constraint or a not null constraint for example.

The following query will tell you all:

```
SELECT * FROM all_constraints WHERE constraint_name = 'PK_TABLENAME'
```

Comment: The name is assigned by whoever created it (unless it's a default `SYS$` name), and it is a common pattern to use `PK_<tablename>`. But it is just a manually-maintained data standard, so you should indeed query the `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` table to check it really is referring to `<tablename>`. I'm not sure it's clear that the naming isn't automatic, and I've seen a few oddities where they've gone out of step for some reason...

Comment: Thanks, I used this and found a bit more useful information in the all_constraints. And the tablename was indeed the one after PK_.